# Strange behaviour when using echo to append to file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

my problem is the following one, I have a bash script that reads a CSV, runs a command, and uses the output of such command to write a new CSV file, but the CSV isn't writing as expected.
The script goes a little bit like this:

```
echo "Strain,Type,SeqTec,Reads,SamclipReads,PercTrimmedReads" > $OUTPUT
while IFS="," read -r strain type state seqtec
do
    OUTRM=$(samtools view -c $RMDIR$strain$RMEND)
    OUTBAM=$(samtools view -c $BAMDIR$strain$BAMEND)
    PERC=$(awk "BEGIN {print ($OUTBAM - $OUTRM)*100 / $OUTBAM}")
    echo $strain,$type,$seqtec,$OUTBAM,$OUTRM,$PERC >> $OUTPUT
done < $INPUT
```

The output is the following (using `head outfile.csv`):

```
Strain,Type,SeqTec,Reads,SamclipReads,PercTrimmedReads
,17539382,16123818,8.07077
,17597797,16078099,8.63573
,16617830,15385883,7.4134
,16431966,15144807,7.83326
```

And the expected output is:

```
Strain,Type,SeqTec,Reads,SamclipReads,PercTrimmedReads
strain1,type1,tec1,17539382,16123818,8.07077
strain2,type2,tec2,17597797,16078099,8.63573
strain3,type3,tec3,16617830,15385883,7.4134
strain4,type4,tec4,16431966,15144807,7.83326
```

I´ve also tried (without success):

```
echo "${strain},${type},${seqtec},${OUTBAM},${OUTRM},${PERC}" >> $OUTPUT
```

I also tried using `printf`, which didn´t work either:

```
printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s" "$strain" "$type" "$seqtec" "$OUTBAM" "$OUTRM" "$PERC" >> $OUTPUT
```

The output using `printf` was:

```
Strain,Type,SeqTec,Reads,SamclipReads,PercTrimmedReads
,17539382,16123818,8.07077
,17597797,16078099,8.63573
,16617830,15385883,7.4134
,16431966,15144807,7.83326
```

Does anyone know why this is behaving like this? I´ve tried many other things without success, does anyone can think of a solution to this?

Comment: Can you provide some sample inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$INPUT` has Windows (DOS) line endings.

You can convert it to unix line endings using `dos2unix` or by adding `\r` to the input field separator:

Using `dos2unix` with process substitution:

```
while IFS="," read -r strain type state seqtec
do
    OUTRM=$(samtools view -c $RMDIR$strain$RMEND)
    OUTBAM=$(samtools view -c $BAMDIR$strain$BAMEND)
    PERC=$(awk "BEGIN {print ($OUTBAM - $OUTRM)*100 / $OUTBAM}")
    echo $strain,$type,$seqtec,$OUTBAM,$OUTRM,$PERC >> "$OUTPUT"
done < <(dos2unix < "$INPUT")
```

Using the alternate field separator:

```
while IFS=$',\r' read -r strain type state seqtec
do
    OUTRM=$(samtools view -c $RMDIR$strain$RMEND)
    OUTBAM=$(samtools view -c $BAMDIR$strain$BAMEND)
    PERC=$(awk "BEGIN {print ($OUTBAM - $OUTRM)*100 / $OUTBAM}")
    echo $strain,$type,$seqtec,$OUTBAM,$OUTRM,$PERC >> "$OUTPUT"
done < "$INPUT"
```

Comment: Even easier: use `while IFS=$',\r' read -r ...`, and it'll treat the carriage return as whitespace and trim it.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Good idea. I put that in as an alternative.

Comment: Thanks, you were right, the problem was the DOS line endings.

Comment: @Iseez Great! You're welcome!